# How to set sec-fetch-site?

Tags: http, https, http-headers, fetch-api

I tried setting it to `none` like this but always reverts to `cross-site`:

```
await fetch("https://example.com/api/orgs", {
            headers: {
                "sec-fetch-site": "none"
            },
            redirect:"error", 
            cache:"no-cache",
            credentials:"include"
        })
    }
```

I tried setting mode as `no-cors`, that don't seem to be the correct way since other are able to do without such hacks.

Here is the request which I want to simulate:

```
"request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://example.com/api/orgs",
          "httpVersion": "http/2.0",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": ":authority",
              "value": "example.com"
            },
            {
              "name": ":method",
              "value": "GET"
            },
            {
              "name": ":path",
              "value": "/api/orgs"
            },
            {
              "name": ":scheme",
              "value": "https"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept",
              "value": "*/*"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-encoding",
              "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
            },
            {
              "name": "accept-language",
              "value": "en-US,en-GB;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7"
            },
            {
              "name": "cache-control",
              "value": "max-age=0"
            },
            {
              "name": "cookie",
              "value": "sessionKey=sk-ant-sid01-K_s_xmr8dbkavt3VJSWWZ2cppIGBXky0kMVrSC18fbO7P9Sk5kO8WrnSHTog9CSf5UObBcKmb1iUFR8IZr-ZFA-xnuU6QAA; intercom-device-id-lupk8zyo=f9cffb16-1e83-4530-826c-f115b81d263f; __cf_bm=RkmGpsF2xDpWH2hAxwIz2vvbtHHo2ir3YbOE1CP7c48-1692183660-0-ATloIxeBE7TN8lXy4uOSj2LjMzIJu3Kpm79t6YmxWXUDZG9DEXurgVysZ0xgM2FAZbC2xiaa0lZkYmbFpJxeGrw=; cf_clearance=MNb33ssXp_pGuBplB_po0M0C5KexvZ00e0Gva.H8jjA-1692183663-0-1-b0a4294d.1884524.e7a576ad-0.2.1692183663; intercom-session-lupk8zyo=THlxaFM1L0xWeTJDdGdBRG1QdmxNUExqKytRb1h0YXVqdGh0SERINm9VRjQwQlR6OUNaTmdTOWE0ZWZCMEEzcy0tZWIyUUxjanA4VGM1dm4vU3JKU0kxdz09--07ac6ee766832e6a8a61be8555c654c3fc154046"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua",
              "value": "\"Not.A/Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"114\", \"Brave\";v=\"114\""
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua-mobile",
              "value": "?0"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-ch-ua-platform",
              "value": "\"macOS\""
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-dest",
              "value": "empty"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-mode",
              "value": "cors"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-fetch-site",
              "value": "none"
            },
            {
              "name": "sec-gpc",
              "value": "1"
            },
            {
              "name": "user-agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [
            {
              "name": "sessionKey",
              "value": "sk-ant-sid01-K_s_xmr8dbkavt3VJSWWZ2cppIGBXky0kMVrSC18fbO7P9Sk5kO8WrnSHTog9CSf5UObBcKmb1iUFR8IZr-ZFA-xnuU6QAA",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": "example.com",
              "expires": "2023-09-09T11:21:08.587Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "Strict"
            },
            {
              "name": "intercom-device-id-lupk8zyo",
              "value": "f9cffb16-1e83-4530-826c-f115b81d263f",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": ".example.com",
              "expires": "2023-08-23T11:01:06.828Z",
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": false,
              "sameSite": "Lax"
            },
            {
              "name": "__cf_bm",
              "value": "RkmGpsF2xDpWH2hAxwIz2vvbtHHo2ir3YbOE1CP7c48-1692183660-0-ATloIxeBE7TN8lXy4uOSj2LjMzIJu3Kpm79t6YmxWXUDZG9DEXurgVysZ0xgM2FAZbC2xiaa0lZkYmbFpJxeGrw=",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": ".example.com",
              "expires": "2023-08-16T11:31:00.160Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "cf_clearance",
              "value": "MNb33ssXp_pGuBplB_po0M0C5KexvZ00e0Gva.H8jjA-1692183663-0-1-b0a4294d.1884524.e7a576ad-0.2.1692183663",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": ".example.com",
              "expires": "2024-02-12T11:01:03.173Z",
              "httpOnly": true,
              "secure": true,
              "sameSite": "None"
            },
            {
              "name": "intercom-session-lupk8zyo",
              "value": "THlxaFM1L0xWeTJDdGdBRG1QdmxNUExqKytRb1h0YXVqdGh0SERINm9VRjQwQlR6OUNaTmdTOWE0ZWZCMEEzcy0tZWIyUUxjanA4VGM1dm4vU3JKU0kxdz09--07ac6ee766832e6a8a61be8555c654c3fc154046",
              "path": "/",
              "domain": ".example.com",
              "expires": "2023-08-23T11:01:06.000Z",
              "httpOnly": false,
              "secure": false,
              "sameSite": "Lax"
            }
          ],
          "headersSize": -1,
          "bodySize": 0
        }
```